# How to get input from template in view in django

Tags: python, django, web-applications, django-templates, django-views

I know this question is too primitive but I'm totally new in web application development and I still haven't found an answer for it. When you want to receives some data from the user like the number of products the user wants to buy in a template like this:

```
form action="/pay/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <label for="pid">Book ID</label>  
    <input type="text" name="pid" value={{pid}} />
    <br/>
    <label for="sid">Seller ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="sid" value={{sid}} />
    <br/>    
    <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="http://localhost:8000/payment/success" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="http://localhost:8000/payment/cancel"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="http://localhost:8000/payment/error"  />
    <p>Checksum test: {{checksum}}</p>
    <input type="text" name="checksum" value={{checksum}}/>
    </br>
    <label for="id_amount">Please enter the number of products you would like to buy </label>
    <input type="text" id="id_amount" name="amount" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="Accept payment" />
</form>
```

how do you read that input in the view? For example, how can I print that input?

My view is like this:

```
def get_payment_detail(request, pid, sid):    
    checksum = Payment().calc_checksum()   
    return render_to_response('payment/payment.html', RequestContext(request, {'pid':Payment.pid,
                        'sid':Payment.sid,
                        'amount':Payment.amount,
                        'checksum': checksum                     
                        }))
```

Comment: You're missing one of the beautiful features of django.Using forms makes your life easier and you can forget adding validations to the form.

Comment: I was actually trying use that from this link: http://www.peachybits.com/2011/09/django-1-3-form-api-modelform-example/ but the order of the things I have to do was a bit confusing.  What I want to do is to have a view that shows a form to the user. The user inputs something, I get that input and together with other stuff send it to an external server. But so far I totally messed up doing that! If you could help me it would be really really nice of you.

Comment: Check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923317/creating-django-forms

Comment: I'm using the link you sent me. It's very nice! But if I want to calculate a checksum from the entries I got from the HTML and add it to the form, how do I do that?

Comment: My view looks like this: def pay(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PaymentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            checksum = PaymentModel().calc_checksum()
            myModel = form.save()
            myModel.checksum = calc_checksum()
        else:
            print form.errors
    else: # The request is GET  
        form = PaymentForm()
    return render_to_response('payment/payment.html', {'form':form})

Answer (score 3):

You can access the form data off of request.POST.  For example:

```
request.POST['pid']
```

Comment: .. but you really ought to be using Django's forms framework.