# Pass data POSTed via ajax in Django to HTML

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a form that I submitted via Ajax and would like to pass the processed data to the same HTML for data input.

Not sure if it is correct, I have posted data to url `/cat_select`and plan to fetch the value processed in Python in the same url, but I am having problem getting data back.

Below is the `POST` function

```
def cat_select(request):
    cat_result=[]
    cat_selected=[]
    cat_name=['l2','l3']
    cat_selected=list(map(lambda x:request.POST.get(x, '').split(','), cat_name))
    cat_result=c_result(["US"],cat_selected) #list of tuples I want to get 
    print(cat_selected)
    print(cat_result)
    return JsonResponse({'cat':cat_result},safe=False)
```

When I open `/cat_select` for `cat_result`, I get empty list, instead of what's printed in Python console. How can I access the processed values?

I want to have `cat_result` on web page. I would like to have the data getting processed after submitting the form and then back, but the browser seems to `GET` data before `POST` with below code.

```
<form id="cat_select">{% csrf_token %} 
<input class="site" name="site" type="text">
<input class="l2" name="l2" id="l2" type="text" style="width:30%">
<input class="l3" name="l3" id="l3" type="text" style="width:50%">
<br>
<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" id="cat_submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('submit','#cat_select',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/cat_select',
        data:{
            l2:$('#l2').val(),
            l3:$('#l3').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        success: function(){
            alert ("selected!")
        }
    });
      $.ajax({
                method:'GET',
                url:'/cat_select',
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    alert ("Data back!")
                },
                error:function(data){
                    console.log('Error!');
                }
            });
});
</script>
```

If a second URL need to be used for processed data, how can I do it in FBV? Thanks.

(**UPDATE** I am not using django form as the inputs are wrapped with selectize.js. Is there another way other than django forms?)

Answer (score 0):

From your code I get the idea that you are trying to create a form with fields and submit button. But I honestly do not know why didn’t you use Django forms as it is very easy and straight forward 
[Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/)

You do not need to do what you are doing. Unless you are doing something else in which you can explain more so we can help

I only did what you did when I needed to send more than one post request to the same page, in which I needed to update a variable every time user does something
mine was when a user stops a video post the current second of the video in which I handled in another script, but the script that sends the data I need

```
///function that POSTS the remining time andd video id
function PostVideoData() {
    var newinput =     document.getElementById("remtime").value;
var video_id = document.getElementById("video_id").value;
if (newinput != input) {
    input = newinput;

}
var saveData = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:   "lectures/video/",
    data: {"value": input,   "video_id" : video_id},
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(resultData){

  }
});


}
```

And i just called the function

For your type of issue, use forms, just search Django forms and you will find enough information to fix your issue
Also visit this question

[creating django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923317/creating-django-forms)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not using Django form as the inputs are using selectize.js which I already passed possible option through `render` in `views.py`.

Answer (score 0):

The data can be accessed via the success callback of your ajax POST request:

```
success: function(response, status, XHR){
        var data = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.cat);
    }
```

To clarify, I think you are trying to access the data from your second ajax request, but you can’t do this because http requests are *stateless*, which means that each request knows nothing about previous requests, and any variables defined in previous requests are forgotten in new requests.

TLDR; you don’t need the second ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is this possible to access cat_selected or cat_result in another function that renders context in views.py?

Comment: How to use **TLDR** in ajax?